# navigation bar keeps reappearing

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I have a tab bar controller with 3 tabs. Each tab has a navigation controller embedded. In the first tab, and in the first view controller in this tab, I have set the navigation bar to hidden, like so:

```
     self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
```

When navigating in the first tab, the navigation bar always behaves correctly as it should. However, when I switch from tab 1 to either tab 2 or 3, and then go back to tab 1, the navigation bar appears. I tried putting the above code in both viewWillAppear and viewDidDLoad, and neither works. In the IB, for the navigation controller I unchecked "bar visibility-show navigation bar", and under "simulated metrics" I set "Top Bar" to none.

This is a tableview controller, and in the view hierarchy there is a navigation item, and I tried deleting it but I can't--I trued both highlighting it and clicking "delete" on my keyboard and also dragging it to the trash can--neither work.  Any idea how I can keep this from reappearing every time when I navigate back from other tabs?

Answer (score 0):

Well you could try this to hide it:

```
func hide(){
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {

            self.navigationController?.alpha = 0.0

            }, completion: nil)
}

func show(){
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {

                self.navigationController?.alpha = 1.0

                }, completion: nil)
}
```